# Where do you write the logic for Fragments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

Is it right to write everything on onCreateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are supposed to update any UI element from code (setting up some button text or something), your UI elements wouldn't be ready until onCreate, onCreateView finish execution. You can manage some part of operation in onViewCreated(when this will be executed, your UI elements will be available to you).

If there is some initial setup you need for your fragment (like setting up of some variables/callbacks/db connections), you can do that from onCreate safely.

However I would recommend to write your logic in separate functions and call those functions from overridden onResume() method so that UI rendering from XML would be completed already by the time you start updating them programatically. Even if there is no UI update you are planning to do, you can do whatever work you want to do from your own function which you called from onResume() only.

This flow diagram should help you plan your work better.

Link : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating

Answer (score 0):

It is good to write the View Logics inside onCreateView as this method returns the View for the Fragment to draw. Inorder to retain significant component data, it is preferred to write it up inside OnCreate method.[Check out this Fragment Lifecycles Guide and their descriptions for more](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)